# what is the use of trace flags in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

am SQL beginner I want to know why we use trace flags and the usage of Trace flag 3608 , trace flag 1204 and trace flag 1400.

Comment: Why those trace flags specifically? Looks like a bit of a haphazard collection from Andrew's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Trace flags are a way of configuring certain aspects of SQL Server behviour, depending on how it is set it can be a temporary change to SQL Server behaviour, or a permanent one. They should not be used lightly, or without full knowledge of the effects that they can have.

Copied from the trace flags doc : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx

1204 : Returns the resources and types of locks participating in a deadlock and also the current command affected.

1400 : Enabled database mirroring, the RTM release of 2005 had it swtiched off by default.

3608 : Prevents SQL Server from automatically starting and recovering any database except the master database. Databases will be started and recovered when accessed. Some features, such as snapshot isolation and read committed snapshot, might not work. Use for Moving System Databases and Moving User Databases. Do not use during normal operation.

Please do notice the warning about not using 3608 - some of the trace flags are not officially supported and using them is at your own risk.

If in any doubt - do not use them.